# How to add subcategories to given categories in the spinner?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-spinner

```java
String[] categories = {
    "All",
    "Surgeon",
    "Pediatrician",
    "Cardiologist",
    "Dermatologist"
};
ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
//Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
drspin.setAdapter(aa);
drspin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String a = drspin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        sd.setText(a);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView << ? > parent) {

    }
});
```

**I have created a spinner having categories, and now I want to add the doctor's name in the subcategories, but I am not able to do it.**

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and be more specific? What do you mean by "not able to do it"? What code did you write for this? What happens when you run it, and what did you expect to happen  instead? See also [ask].

Comment: @Robert hey, In the above code I have made a spinner with 4 to 5 categories, now I want to add subcategories to those categories, and I don't know how it will happen, I went through many other solutions but No results.